# How do I add the UIApplicationDelegate to the end of the UIResponder chain?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiresponder

I'm trying to provide an `IBAction` method for common functionality that is required at various parts of the app.

i.e. Login is implemented modally, and if it succeeds results in a notification that allows all loaded view controllers to react to this event (transition from anonymous to authenticated)

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
  ...
}
- (IBAction)loginTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

I set the action of that button to the First Responder in IB, however the responder chain doesn't give `MyAppDelegate` a chance to respond.

My problem is that, I don't want to replicate the method at various parts of the responder chain, I would like to add it to a common class that is already a subclass.

The `UIResponder` chain goes all the way through to the `UIApplication` but that seems to be the end. My `UIApplicationDelegate` doesn't get to participate.

I want to insert or add my app delegate to the responder chain!

*(or find another way to hook up the `UIButton` touch-up-inside to an app-wide implementation.. I want to avoid subclassing the `UITabBarController` or `UIWindow` if possible)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `UIApplication` to have `-nextResponder` return the application delegate if it is a `UIResponder` subclass.  You'll then need to alter your call to `UIApplicationMain` to use your custom subclass.

I haven't tried this myself, but I can't think of any immediate problems this would cause.

Comment: I would like to avoid subclassing anything if possible. The Apple docs guide you away from subclassing `UIApplication`: *"there is rarely a valid need to extend this class; ... be very sure of what you are trying to accomplish with the subclass."*

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 5, the AppDelegate is automatically the last link in the responder chain. Xcode project templates will create an AppDelegate that is a subclass of `UIResponder` rather than `NSObject`. However, to avoid cluttering up the AppDelegate, override the AppDelegate's `nextResponder` and offload work into a custom `UIResponder` object:

```
- (UIResponder *)nextResponder
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static LastUIResponder *lastResponder = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        lastResponder = [[LastUIResponder alloc] init];
    });
    return lastResponder;
}
```